# How to correctly size containing views

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, view, size

I have an `Activity` that will display a custom view made up of 2 parts.  I want one part to be 1/3 of visible screen height, the other part to be 2/3.

I can override `onMeasure()` and use display metrics to find the height of the display, but this does not account for the battery bar or view title sizes.

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics(); 
((WindowManager)contxt.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm); 
int height = dm.heightPixels;
```

How can I tell the height of the displayable area?  I'm prepared to override the `layout` or whatever.  What is the `Android`'s best practices?  I've seen other questions along this line, but they are inconclusive.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to do it.  I override RelativeLayout, and get it to keep pointers to my upper and lower views.  Then when it processes onMeasure, it sets the desired heights on my 2 views.  They use the desired height when they handle onMeasure.  This gives me one view at 2/3 of the visible area, with the other one below.

-- from my Layout class

```
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // set default screen heights
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    if ( upper != null )
        upper.setPrefHeight((heightSize*2)/3);
    if ( lower != null )
        lower.setPrefHeight(heightSize/3);

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

}
```

-- from the View derived classes

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec),
            measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec));
}

/**
 * Determines the width of this view
 * @param measureSpec A measureSpec packed into an int
 * @return The width of the view, honoring constraints from measureSpec
 */
private int measureWidth(int measureSpec) {
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        // We were told how big to be
        result = specSize;
    } else {
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics(); 
        ((WindowManager)contxt.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm); 
        result = dm.widthPixels; 
    }
    width = result;
    return result;
}

/**
 * Determines the height of this view
 * @param measureSpec A measureSpec packed into an int
 * @return The height of the view, honoring constraints from measureSpec
 */
private int measureHeight(int measureSpec) {
    int result = 0;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

    if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        // We were told how big to be
        result = specSize;
    } else {
        result = prefHeight;
    }
    height = result;

    return result;
}
```